# tomcat6 installation on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat6, apt-get

I want to install tomcat6 on my ubuntu server, but I am getting error when I say 
`sudo apt-get install tomcat6`. When I install tomcat7, I can succesfully install it.
But I get this error during installing tomcat6,

```
    ubuntu@ip-10-202-47-144:/var/solr$ sudo apt-get install tomcat6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tomcat6 : Depends: tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.35-1ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure the tomcat 7 or any other version of tomcat is removed before installing tomcat 6 here is how you can remove it

```
sudo apt-get remove tomcat7-common
```

here is link for you
https://askubuntu.com/questions/173981/installing-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-server-12-04

Comment: np, I am happy I could help.